# LINQ select EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

So. Controller:

```
public Device.DeviceDBContext db5 = new Device.DeviceDBContext();
var d1 = from d in db5.Devices
       where d.gre == "GRE-0495"
       select d;
doc.Devices.Add(d1.First());
```

Model:

```
public class Doc
    {
    // Unrelated fields omitted

    public ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    }
```

Second model file:

```
public class Device
    {
       // Unrelated omitted
       public string gre { get; set; }

       public class DeviceDBContext : DbContext
       {
           public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
       }
    }
```

I double-checked the database that some Device had `d.gre == "GRE-0495"`, it was there. And the exact error I get is below. I caught it inside the last line in the controller.

```
'((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Device_EA17FD29B09167FED4AB0C5AD1E7CF460032C2D49C4002FFBF9D395CB5849D5A)new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<steer.Models.Device>(d1).Items[0]).Docs' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException'
```

The breakpoint shows that d1 is populated with the correct data with `gre=="GRE-0495"`.

Comment: Whats the Inner exception, I think the problem is on the Add bit. Shouldn't you be copying the element before adding it again to the Context? Otherwise you are adding an already existing element.

Comment: try adding `.AsEnumerable()` to db5.Devices in the linq query?

Comment: Did not know you could check for an inner exception, thanks. The inner exception is "Invalid object name 'dbo.Devices'"